# Ordering table data from separate JSON file by using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, database, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to sort the data in the units section alphabetically from the data that has been fetched from a JSON file. Before, I have tried to create another filter controller for the data, use GroupBy or OrderBy within the table data headers. The result I've gotten is as [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toxVI.png) where the units table disappears after any implementation of sort into the table.

The original output: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2RmP.png), where by the Units column should be alphabetically ordered.

I appreciate any advice given ,thank you very much!

**HTML/units4.html**

```
<div data-ng-controller="getCtrl" class="container">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <pre>Status Code: {{status}}</pre>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
                        <caption>Table 1: Unit Information</caption>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <th id="code">
                                Code
                            </th>
                            <th id="units">
                                Units
                            </th>
                            <th id="credits">
                                Credit points
                            </th>
                            <th id="type">
                                Type
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="success" data-ng-repeat="subject in course">
                            <td headers="code">
                                {{subject.Codes}}
                            </td>
                            <td headers="units" data-ng-repeat="subject in Units | orderBy = 'Units'">
                                {{subject.Units}}
                            </td>
                            <td headers="credits">
                                {{subject.Credits | number:2}}
                            </td>
                            <td headers="type">
                                {{subject.Type}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**AngularJS/appunits4.js**

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller ("getCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/course.json').then (
        // Successful response
        function(response) {
            $scope.course = response.data;
            $scope.status = response.status;
        },
        // Bad response
        function(response) {
            $scope.status = response.status || "File not found";
        }        
    );
});
```

**Brief JSON Data Code: data/course.json**

```
[
{
    "Codes"     : "ICT10001",
    "Units"     : "Problem Solving with ICT",
    "Credits"   : "12.5",
    "Type"      : "Core"
},            
{
    "Codes"     : "COS10005",
    "Units"     : "Web Development",
    "Credits"   : "12.5",
    "Type"      : "Core"
},
{
    "Codes"     : "INF10003",
    "Units"     : "Introduction to Business Information System",
    "Credits"   : "12.5",
    "Type"      : "Core"
},
{
    "Codes"     : "INF10002",
    "Units"     : "Database Analysis and Design",
    "Credits"   : "12.5",
    "Type"      : "Core"
},
{
    "Codes"     : "COS10009",
    "Units"     : "Introduction to Programming",
    "Credits"   : "12.5",
    "Type"      : "Core"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead of Your HTML code

```
 <tr class="success" data-ng-repeat="subject in course| orderBy:'Units'">
                                <td headers="code">
                                    {{subject.Codes}}
                                </td>
                                <td headers="units" >
                                    {{subject.Units}}
                                </td>
                                <td headers="credits">
                                    {{subject.Credits | number:2}}
                                </td>
                                <td headers="type">
                                    {{subject.Type}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you! Manage to work on your part, I was confused on where to place the expression,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a plugin like angular-datatables ?

[See here](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withAjax)

Answer (score 0):

You are using **orderBy** incorrectly,

**orderBy** clause should be used as mentioned in [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

> **{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse : comparator}}**

Try below code:

```
<td headers="units" data-ng-repeat="subject in Units | orderBy : 'Units'">
                                                               /\
                                                               ||
                                                               ||
                                                               ||
```

It should be colon `:` not assigment `=` operator.

**Note:** Always check browser's console for the error message, it will help you for sure

Comment: Thank you, I understand much better now !